# Makefile splitting variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am having an set of event as INPUT in makefile and I would like to assign them with EVENT_1, EVENT_2...so on so forth. And I would also like to check the number of events in INPUT variable, is there a way I can do this?

I have tried the following:

```
INPUT=g1 g2

all:
    for eventid in INPUT; do \
        echo evenit; \
        i+=1; \
    done 
    echo i
```

seems that i only valid in the loop and I could not check the eventid and number of event outside the loop.

After this, I would like to make use of eventid and number to have targets like "generate_EVENT1". Is it possible?

Comment: about the number of events, I tried NUMBER=$(words, $(INPUT)) and then echo $(NUMBER) in all. I've got two events in INPUT but it showed a number of 1.

Comment: Creating the `generate_EVENT...` rules is easy; assigning values to `EVENT_1`, `EVENT_2` and so on is a pain. Do you need `EVENT_1` outside the `generate_EVENT1` rule?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve by creating the EVENT_1, EVENT_2, ... Make can work with array `$(work n, array)`, more flexible that create the make symbols

Comment: @Beta, my idea is to make something like `all: generate_EVENT1, generate_EVENT2` and mkdir directories for each events. While there are rules for target generate_EVENT1/2 as well.

Comment: @dash-0, thanks, though there is typo in your code which should be `$(word n, array)` instead, I could assign eventid with the corresponding input. However, I am seeking a way to allow flexible input of INPUT events. That is if I change the number of input events to 3 or 4, the makefile could detect the number of array element and assign each element with eventid.

Comment: You're leaving out vital details. *What do you want the directories to be called?*

Comment: @Beta, for example, I have event names G1 and S2. They are directories under `run_dir` and there is a `generate_run_1` in both `G1` and `S2` directories. I want to have rules with `generate_run_G1` and `generate_run_S2` to classify them in makefile. At last I will change their names back to `generate_run_1`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the amount of elements in `INPUT`:

```make
COUNT := $(words $(INPUT))
```

Generate a rule and create a folder for each element in `INPUT`:

```make
INPUT := g1 g2

.PHONY: all

all: $(addprefix run_dir/generate_, $(INPUT))

run_dir/generate_%:
    mkdir -p $@
```

You can also omit the `INPUT` variable declaration and call make like so:

```make
make INPUT="g1 g2"
```

Comment: I tried your code and it appeared "make: Nothing to be done for `all' ." 
And by ".SECONDEXPANSION" I think you are pointing to object $(addprefix generate_, $(INPUT)) so I created an variable: "HELLO = $(addprefix generate_, $(INPUT))"

Comment: @Simon219 `.SECONDEXPANSION` was used to enable a second pass on the automatic variable `$*` (which was escaped with another `$`) because automatic variables have no content when used in prerequisites at first pass. I've updated the answer, directories should be created now.